# (C++) What's wrong with this code?. Please

Tags: c++

I have to double the vowels (E.g.: home -> hoomee, shooter -> shooooteer).
What have I done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[100],*p;
    unsigned int i,j;
    cin.get(s,100);
    p=s;
    for(i=0;i<=strlen(p);i++)
    {
        if((p[i]=='a')||(p[i]=='e')||(p[i]=='i')||(p[i]=='o')||(p[i]=='u'))
        {
            for(j=strlen(p);j>p[i];j--)
                p[j]=p[j-1];
            p[i+1]=p[i];
            p++;
        }
    }
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through your code line by line. That way you will see everything that's going on, and the values of all variables and how they change. Then of course you should know that `p[strlen(p)]` of course is the terminating character in the string, so your outer loop condition isn't really correct.

Comment: Oh, and as for the problem you're trying to solve, have you thought about having *two* strings? Then the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg then, how can I make space for the new vocals? strlen(s)+i ?

Comment: So, copying the first one, character by character and when I find a vocal, double it?

Comment: @Krinsken:  `if (p[i] == 'a' ...) {result.push_back(p[i]);} result.push_back(p[i]);'

Comment: If you want to do the shuffle-up thing, look at memmove.  But beware: Your code will break horribly if I enter 100 vowels (why would I do that? because I've spent some time in the company of professional testers.)

Comment: @Krinsken The new string will be at most twice the length, so you don't need more than `2 * strlen(s) + 1`. Or just use `char s2[200];`.

Comment: And if you're only interested in the output, you don't need to copy anything anywhere - just print character by character and print the vowels twice.

Answer (score 2):

think about p++; line every time you do that you move pointer p on 1 position so finally p won't point on first element of buffer s.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
for(j=strlen(p);j>p[i];j--)
    p[j]=p[j-1];
```

there are at least two errors. The first one than when `j` is set to `strlen( p )` then the terminating zero is overwritten.

The second one is that the condition `j>p[i]` should be written at least like `j > i`.

Then after the loop pointer `p` is changed

```
p++;
```

As result expression `strlen(p)` will give incorrect value for the length of the string.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype> 

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const size_t N = 100;
        char s[N];
        s[0] = '\0';

        std::cout << "Enter a string (empty string - exit): ";
        std::cin.getline( s, N );

        if ( s[0] == '\0' ) break;

        const char *vowels = "AEIOU";

        size_t n = std::strlen( s );

        for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( std::strchr( vowels, std::toupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) )
            {
                if ( n + 1 < N )
                {
                    ++n;
                    std::memcpy( p + 1, p, n - ( p - s ) );
                }
                else
                {                    
                    std::memmove( p + 1, p, n - ( p - s ) - 1 );
                }                    
                ++p;
            }
        }

        printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );
    }        
}
```

If to enter at first

```
home
```

then

```
shooter
```

and at last just press Enter then the output will look like

```
Enter a string (empty string - exit): home
"hoomee"
Enter a string (empty string - exit): shooter
"shooooteer"
Enter a string (empty string - exit):
```